# Changing values of an app theme at runtime

Tags: android, runtime, android-theme, material-design

My app requires to change certain atributes of the app theme (like colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent)

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/i_need_runtime</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/me_too</item>
```

But these changes must be done at runtime, because these values are coming via webservice (json). Because there isn't any api to change the values of a theme at runtime, I think that the only way would be changing the resources values defined at xml via Java Reflection, but I don't know how to do it because in R.java there are defined ids, not the value itself.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Themes cannot be modified, in Android, at runtime. However, for API 21 or more, you can call

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(int color) 

getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(int color)
```

in your Activity to set colors programatically.